# VScode で Ruby の自動整形を使いたいが 「フォーマッタがインストールされていません」と出てしまう

Tags: ruby, vscode

VSCode にて「Shift +  Option + F」で自動整形機能を使いたいのですが、
「rubyファイルのフォーマッタがインストールされていません」と出てしまいます。

右下部の「フォーマッタをインストール」ボタンから出てくる候補を色々試してみたのですが、
うまく機能するものが見つかりませんでした。

なお、「VScode ruby フォーマッタ」で検索して調査済みです。
VSCodeを分かる方がいらっしゃれば、アドバイスをいただきたいです。

Comment: これらのどれかが参考になるかも。[How do I auto format Ruby or .erb files in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41051423/9014308), [VSCodeでRubyを書く準備](https://qiita.com/yumikokh/items/98be01df144c41d60e1e), [rubocopを使わずに5分で綺麗なRubyにフォーマットする方法](https://shanshan.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2018/12/23/093125)

Answer (score 1):

フォーマット用のgemがインストールされていないのではないでしょうか？
フォーマッタにも色々あると思いますが、私は[rufo](https://github.com/ruby-formatter/rufo)を使用しています。

例えばrufoを使ってrubyのコードをフォーマットしたいなら、まず次のようにgemをインストールします。

```
$ gem install rufo
```

そしてVSCode用の拡張機能[rufo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mbessey.vscode-rufo)をインストールすれば、フォーマットできるようになります。

その他、[rubocopを使用してフォーマットする](https://qiita.com/yumikokh/items/98be01df144c41d60e1e)こともできるようです。